How can I link metaboxes to a specific page?
In the ACF admin, if you create a field, you can set the parameter where to display this metabox Show this field group if and set, for example, page = about and in this way display metaboxes only on the About page
If you do it through code
'location' => array (
                array (
                    array (
                        'param' => 'post_type',
                        'operator' => '==',
                        'value' => 'page',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

it is possible this way, but then only on ALL pages
'location' => array (
                array (
                    array (
                        'param' => 'page_type',
                        'operator' => '==',
                        'value' => 'front_page',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

Or like this, the main one.
But I don't quite understand how to specify which page to link to.
I want to link metaboxes to a specific page, "about-us"
<?php
acf_add_local_field_group(array (
    'key' => 'group_1',
    'title' => 'My Group',
    'fields' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'field_1',
            'label' => 'Sub Title',
            'name' => 'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text',
            'prefix' => '',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array (
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'maxlength' => '',
            'readonly' => 0,
            'disabled' => 0,
        )
    ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param' => 'page_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'front_page',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'normal',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
));


Have you tried using the page_id?
Within your location you could set the "Param" to "page" and the "value" to the page_ID.
I often use the export to PHP function from ACF if I´m not sure which values are required.

If you want to display the ACF Field for a specific page you could change your 'location' to the following:
'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'page',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => '10',
            ),
        ),
    ),

10 = page-ID for the desired site.
FYI:
I often use the ACF-Export to PHP function if I´m not sure which values are required when creating fields by code.
I temporarily create the fields within the ACF admin and use the export tool to see the required code.



Hope it helps you a little further.

I had a similar need, but didn't want to use IDs, as that can change across environments, or in the future, so I created a plugin to create a page slug rule.
Add that file in the wp-content/mu-plugins directory, and when editing your field group, there will be a new "Page Slug" dropdown item.
